# How to replace only the leading zeros with NA?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace leading zeros with NAs? suppose I have the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1': [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 'c2': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]})
```

the goal is to have the following result:

```
 c1    c2
 NA   1.0
 NA   1.0
1.0   1.0
0.0   0.0
```

but doing the following will not work since it will replace all and not just the leading zeros:

```
df[np.abs(df) < 1e-50] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) to fill the non-trailing zeros, and mask those that remain:

```
df.mask(df.cummax().eq(0))
```

Or to handle all non zero values with limited precision:

```
df.mask(df.gt(1e-50).cummax().lt(1e-50))
```

output:

```
    c1   c2
0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: @SkyWalker of course you can use `.lt(1e-50)` if you want

Comment: Would it be possible not to do eq(0) ?? this is a risky bet working with floats which is my case as seen in the OP ... it would be best doing `np.abs(x) > 1e-50`

Comment: Even shorter: `df[df.cummax().ne(0)]`

Comment: Actually the answer should be more like `df.mask(np.abs(df.cummax()).lt(1e-50))`

Comment: @SkyWalker I guess more: `df.mask(df.abs().cummax().lt(1e-50))` (`abs` before `cummax`)

Comment: Or even `df.mask(df.gt(1e-50).cummax().lt(1e-50))`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to mozways' answer, but with assignment and `cummin`:

```
df[df.eq(0).cummin()] = pd.NA
```

Demo:

```
>>> df
    c1   c2
0  0.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0
>>> df.eq(0).cummin()
      c1     c2
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
>>> df[df.eq(0).cummin()] = pd.NA
>>> df
    c1   c2
0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: `pd.NA != np.nan`.

Comment: Hah, but for that matter, `np.nan != np.nan` :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the sign wrong.

if you switch to

```
df[np.abs(df) < 1e-50] = np.nan
```

it should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with `ffill`

```
df[df.mask(df==0).ffill().isna()] = np.nan 
df
Out[141]: 
    c1   c2
0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  1.0
2  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0
```